# SSH to a server within JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ssh

I have a submit button on my UI and when I click it, I need to SSH to a server and run a command on it. The code structure is shown as below :

```
    <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="verifyorder()" />


       function verifyorder() {

        var servername = document.getElementById('servername').value;
        var stime = document.getElementById('demo1').value;
        var etime = document.getElementById('demo2').value;

        // I need to login to a server and pass the above parameters in a command.
}
```

What can be the best way to achieve this? Any inputs would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use some sort of server side code to handle the SSH portion of the work.  Making an SSH connection in javascript would not be an easy (or possible?) task.

Comment: I am not sure which one to use and how. If there are any pointers or links please do share. I googled it for a lot of time but couldn't get a understandable approach

Comment: Depends on what your web server supports.  PHP is pretty common.  It sounds like you may have to do some more research.